# Generic type constraint checking

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to write something that will fail either at compile or runtime (i.e. by any means) on invocation of just one of these methods?

```
public static void Register<TInterface, TImplementation>()
    where TImplementation : class, TInterface
{
}
```

```
public static void RegisterRestrictive<TInterface, TImplementation>()
    where TInterface : class
    where TImplementation : class, TInterface
{
}
```

The following will pass both for example:

```
public interface IInterface
{
}

public class Implementation : IInterface
{
}


public void Test()
{
    Register<IInterface, Implementation>();
    RegisterRestrictive<IInterface, Implementation>();
}
```

I don't think it is, because you can't extend structs?

Asking because of this https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/pull/624

Comment: Throw an exception from inside the method. It will fail. It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: I can't figure out what this question is asking; that isn't even legal code. You're not allowed to make two constraint clauses on the same type parameter! Is one of those `TImplementation`s intended to be `TInterface`?

Comment: @EricLippert sorry that was a typo, meant to be `where TInterface : class`

Comment: @EricLippert, the question boils down to is the `class` constraint on `TInterface` required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is, as I understand:

```
class C<T, U> where T : class, U where U : class { }
class D<T, U> where T : class, U { }
```

*Is there a construction that is legal for `D` that is not legal for `C`*?

Not if `U` and `T` are *closed types*. That is, types that have no type parameters in them.  As Jon Hanna's answer points out, an *open type* can cause a problem here:

```
class N<T, U> where T : class, U { C<T, U> c; D<T, U> d; }
```

`D`'s constraints are not met, so this construction is illegal.

For type arguments which are closed types we can reason as follows:

In `C`, `U` is required by constraint to be a reference type.

In `D`, `T` can be a class, interface, delegate or array. In every case, `U` has to be identical to `T`, or a base class of `T`, or something `T` is convertible to via (possibly variant) implicit reference conversion.  No matter what, `U` is a reference type.

Note though that neither the C# compiler, nor the CLR verifier, nor the JIT compiler are required to deduce that `U` is always going to be a reference type!  The C# compiler can and will in this circumstance, for instance, generate unnecessary boxing instructions on usages of `U`, even though you and I know that `U` is not going to be a value type under construction.

This can lead to situations where a `U` is boxed and then immediately unboxed, and the last time I checked -- which was, uh, ten years ago -- the jitter did not generate optimal code for that scenario.  Since no doubt the jitter has been rewritten one or more times since I last checked, you should probably not take my word for it.

The good practice here is to put the constraint on there and spell it out.

---

Some fun related facts:

You can get into similar situations by pulling shenanigans like

```
class B<T> { public virtual void M<U>(U u) where U : T {} }
class D : B<int> { public override void M<U>(U u) { } }
```

Note that C# does NOT allow you to re-state the constraint, which is now `where U : int`.  But you cannot do a generic construction of `M` with anything other than int.

This can lead to some truly bizarre scenarios in IL generation, because the CLR has a poorly-documented rule whereby it does not allow the "known-to-be-a-reference-type"-ness of a type parameter to change across a virtual override. I redid the codegen for such methods to try to get something that would compile, pass the verifier, and jit efficiently *several* times before giving up and going back to whatever C# 2 did.

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I was just about to answer my own question but no way as beautifully explained! :)

Comment: And I was checking whether you can produce a class that derives from a struct via some hacks. You definitely can in CIL, but neither C# nor CLR will permit that (it's implicitly sealed even if you remove that attribute from the assembly) :-(

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to write something that will fail either at compile or runtime (i.e. by any means) on invocation of just one of these methods?

Yes, this fails at compile time:

```
public static void CallThem<TA, TB>()
    where TB : class, TA
{
    Register<TA, TB>();         // Fine
    RegisterRestrictive<TA, TB>(); // CS0452
}
```

There's no pair of concrete types that match `TInterface` and `TImplementation` for only one of them, but the type-parameter types of a calling method certainly can, and type-parameter types are types we need to consider in designing APIs as well a concrete types.

Constraints do not involve inference of other constraints.

Comment: Sounds like the issue from GitHub that was being referred to.

Comment: Nice one!  I was thinking about only closed constructions but you are absolutely right that an open construction is problematic here.

Comment: By something, I should have meant by providing values for `TInterface` and `TImplementation`! But yes, this is the problem that sparked my interest!! Very good!

Comment: @Mardoxx but I **am** providing values for them, as perhaps my edit makes a bit clearer; type parameter types are still types—are still *values*—when mapped to the type parameter types of another method or class. Of course, if there was a C# (and CLR) rule that allowed it to be inferred that `TInterface` must be a reference type it would also allow it to be inferred that `TA` must be, but there's no such rule (and whether the added complexity of inference would outweigh the benefits is questionable, even aside from the cost all features have).